# How to enable combined filters with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

**For reference, the full code can be obtained [here](https://gist.github.com/manoelpqueiroz/1459c723fcbb8e3d49a02b1dce52aa00)**

I have three select elements which should act as filters on my page, calling the `myfilter` function. Then, within a table, I use the `data-` attribute in some `<td>` elements to "categorise" them without having to set different classes:

```
<select id="formats" onchange="myfilter('formats', 'mytable')">
  <option value="nofilter">--ALL VALUES--</option>
  <option value="apple">Apples</option>
  <option value="orange">Oranges</option>
  <option value="noattr">Unknown</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-format="apple" style="background-color:red;width:10px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td data-model="film" style="background-color:#3ca971;width:10px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td data-type="water" style="background-color:#458985;width:10px">&nbsp;</td>
    <th>1</th>
    <td>Michael</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>M</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The `myfilter` function, adapted from an example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp), retrieves the value of the selected listbox, determines which column it should look up and compares the custom `data-` attribute to the value in order to keep the rows visible or hide them:

```
function myfilter(myelement, reftable) {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, j, txtValue, rowstyle, checkvisible;
    // Obtains the "value" element of the selected listbox
    input = document.getElementById(myelement);
    filter = input.value;

    table = document.getElementById(reftable);
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    switch(myelement) {
        case "formats":
            j = 0;
            break;
        case "models":
            j = 1;
            break;
        case "types":
            j = 2;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[j];
        if (td) {
            // Retrieves the respective "data-" attribute from <td>
            switch(myelement) {
                case "formats":
                    txtValue = td.dataset.format;
                    break;
                case "models":
                    txtValue = td.dataset.model;
                    break;
                case "types":
                    txtValue = td.dataset.type;
            }
            // If there's no style attribute, it's visibleby default
            rowstyle = tr[i].getAttribute("style");
            if (rowstyle == null) {
                checkvisible = true;
            }
            // If it is hidden, getAttribute returns "display: none;"
            else if (rowstyle.includes("none")) {
                checkvisible = false;
            }
            else {
                checkvisible = true;
            }

            // Maintains or hides the row
            if (filter == "nofilter") {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else if ((txtValue == filter) & checkvisible == true) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            }
            else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The Problem**

The way `myfilter` operates allows for combined filter, but with caveats:

- On a single filter, one has to reset to `--ALL VALUES--` before selecting another filter;
- When combining filters, the above rule stops me from dynamically switching values while another filter is in place.

How must I change the JavaScript function in order to have the combined filters work as intended (say, like Excel filters, where you keep one filter and changes the other)? I thought about splitting the function in three, but it ends up with the same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made things quite a bit more complicated by putting the data on the cells rather than on the rows.

Regardless, removing the `onchange` attributes from the `<select>` elements and using this seems to work:

```js
const table = document.getElementById('mytable');
const filters = [
  ['formats', 'format'],
  ['models', 'model'],
  ['types', 'type'],
];
filters.forEach(v => v[0] = document.getElementById(v[0]));
const rows = Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:not(:first-child)')).map(row => {
  return [row, filters.map(v => row.querySelector(`td[data-${v[1]}]`).dataset[v[1]])];
});
const changeHandler = event => {
  const targets = filters.map(v => v[0].value);
  rows.forEach(row => {
    row[0].style.display = targets.every(
      (v,i) => v == 'nofilter' || v == row[1][i]
    ) ? '' : 'none';
  });
};
filters.forEach(v => {
  v[0].addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
});
changeHandler();
```

`filters` is an array of mappings between the `select` id and the cell data name. The id is converted into `<select>` element references.

`rows` is a mapping between the row and its data. This makes it more convenient for performing the filter.

`changeHandler` handles the `<select>` `change` events. It grabs the current `<select>` values and then uses them to determine which rows are shown.

Then we attached `changeHandler` to each `<select>` element and trigger it once to synchronize everything.

Comment: Thanks, I know my implementation wouldn't be optimal, it's my first time handling JS ever. Just out of curiosity, how would you lay out this filter to make it better? I ended up choosing the `data-` attributes because my filter has to work on cells with no text content. Were I to implement it in the `<tr>` elements, would you still recommend using the `data-` attribute?

Comment: Data attributes are fine. It depends on the planned life of the table & its use case. If the data is static or will only see rare, minor changes, then I'd put the data on the rows (since that's what's being filtered) & I'd move the styling into a stylesheet, basing it on the data: For example, `#mytable tr[data-format="apple"] td:nth-child(1) {background-color: red;}`. This way the filter is easier to implement & the colors are automatically derived from the data & so are easy to update. As a beginner, I wouldn't worry to much about it, these are things that will come with practice & study.